# How can I import the BitbucketPS properly via PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, bitbucket

I am trying to automatically clone my Bitbucket via a powershell script. I am currently using the following line of code:

```
git clone https://myUsername@bitbucket.org/project1/project1-database.git --quiet
```

This works as far as it goes, but I would prefer that you have to log in first to clone the repositories because others should also use the script. I have found the following:

```
Import-Module BitbucketPS
New-BitBucketSession -Credential (Get-Credential "")
```

This will create a window where you can enter your credentials. Unfortunately, an error message appears when executing the script:

Import-Module : The specified module "BitbucketPS" was not loaded, because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
module file was found.

My question is how do I extend my script to import the module and connect to BitBucket from the login window?

UPDATE 1

```
if( -not (Test-Path -Path $path+\project1-database -PathType Any ))
    {
        git clone https://bitbucket.org/project1/project1-database.git --quiet
    }
    else
    {
        Set-Location $path+\project1-database
        git pull https://bitbucket.org/project1/project1-database.git --quiet
    }
```

Comment: "I would prefer that you have to log in first to clone the repositories" that's sort of already the case - since the password is not part of the repo URL, you must have credentials cached - so it already behaves according to whatever local git config is present. Simply remove the username from the URL (or parameterize the repo URL so users can provide their own) :)

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. If I leave out the username then it works as you said. Now I want to test it. I logged out of BitBucket and ran the script again. Still I am not asked for the crendentials. 
Do I have to remove my login data somewhere else first?

Comment: Yeah you need to check the global config of the `git` installation: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials

Comment: This works very well. I have additionally looked at the following ticket to delete the credentials: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39608906/12440701

Comment: For systems you admin, you can also use [`cmdkey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmdkey) for (some) credential management scenarios

Comment: I have one last question if possible: 

I have added my code under UPDATE 1. The goal is that if the repository already exists in the folder then the current version of the repository should be pulled. Unfortunately I get an error: 

git : fatal: destination path 'project1-database' already exists and is not an empty directory. 

Do you have a quick solution for this or should I write a new ticket?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241569/discussion-between-mathias-r-jessen-and-doncarlito87).